# Use select_tag or select with two identifyer in a dynamic list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, dynamic

i'm very new on ror.

I try to get a formular to select a count of an dynamic list.

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "sell", :action => "create", :method => "post") do %>   
    <% @given_event.categorys.find(:all, :order => "id").each do |c| %>
        <%=c.name %><br>
        <% c.tickets.find(:all, :order=>"id").each do |t|%> 
        <%= select_tag "orderticket:" +t.id.to_s, options_for_select([ "0", "1", "3" ]) %>
            <%=t.name%>
        <%=(t.price/100)%><br>
        <%end%> 
    <%end%>
```

As you see i listed the tickets with "c.tickets.find..." and then i concat very dirty the identifyer "ticket:"+t.id.to_s" in the select_tag with the id of the ticket and the count someone will order.

What i want to get ist something like this in params: orderticket{1 => {ticket_id=>"1", count => "2"}. So i can iterate through orderticket and always get the ticket_id and the number count for this ticket.

Can anyone help please

Comment: Hey Alex, could you try this? `<%= select_tag :orderticket, options_for_select(['0','1','2']), {:name => "ticket_id[#{t.id}]"} %>`

Comment: Hi Kaeros, thanks for your help.

It returns:

ticket_id: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  '1': '1'
  '2': '0'

Looks nice, how can i iterate to this hash?

Comment: <%params[:ticket_id].to_hash().each do |t|%>
 <%= t[0]%>
 <%= t[1]%>
<%end%> 

This works!

Comment: How about: `params[:ticket_id].each do |key, value| #code end`

Comment: Oh, ok! Glad you solved! :) Could you accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<%= select_tag :orderticket, options_for_select(['0','1','2']), {:name => "ticket_id[#{t.id}]"} %>
```